# No puedo acceder a la ip publica

Tags: aws

intento conectarme a mi web por medio de la ip publica y no hay manera, hago un ping y me da timeout, la verdad no soy experto en aws.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui son los grupos de seguridad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué reglas tienes en el security group? Para pingtienes que permitir el protocolo Ècho Request`. Recuerda que va por ICMP. Igual es eso.

Comment: te subo imagenes con las reglas, dame 2 minutos, edit : si necesitas mas info dimelo y te subo mas capturas

Comment: Mmm, no veo mucho problema con el security group siempre que estés usando el que permite todo. ¿Has hecho un check del resto de posibles problemas? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-connect-internet-gateway/

Comment: ya lo solucione, ahora posteo la solucion

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solucione añadiendo el puerto 80 en ip v4 y ip v6 en grupos de seguridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El puerto 80 no está relacionado con ICMP o Ping. ¿Esto te ha resuelto el Ping o el acceso web?

Comment: si, me lo ha resuelto, ni idea que es icmp.